# Command 'ng serve --host 0.0.0.0' working fine for localhost but APIs not working on different machines, is there any solution for this?

Tags: angular

The thing is when I run the command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` it's working fine for both the `localhost` as well as on the different machines within same network. But, on adding token to the APIs, APIs are not being hit on different machines. It just showing the HTML with CSS without data. It would be great if any solution to this is provided.

I tried with `disableHostCheck` or with port commands but nothing worked as:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true`,

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`

I expect the API response to all the devices within same network but there is no response to other devices except mine which is localhost.

Answer (score 1):

It will be good if you add a proxy to you server.
In package.json file add below code.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
}
```

then create a proxy.config.json file where your package.json file is located.
add below json to proxy.config.json file

```
{
  "/container1/*": {
    "target": "http://10.101.10.11:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
"/container2/*": {
    "target": "http://10.101.10.12:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
"/container3/*": {
    "target": "http://10.101.10.12:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
}
```

start your local server using the command `npm start`

we can give following options to proxy,

```
{
  "/container": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "stackoverflow.com",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "port": 7001
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```